# Lottery random.randint help in python

Tags: python

Heres my program so far

```
import random

def lottery(lottoNumber1,lottoNumber2,lottoNumber3):
    for count in range(1):
        lottoNumber1 = random.randint(1,50)
        print(lottoNumber1)
    for count in range(1):
        lottoNumber2 = random.randint(1,50)
        print(lottoNumber2)
    for count in range(1):
        lottoNumber3 = random.randint(1,50)
        print(lottoNumber3)



    return lottoNumber1,lottoNumber2,lottoNumber3

def main():
    userChoice1 = int(input('Chose a number between 1 and 50: '))
    userChoice2 = int(input('Chose a number between 1 and 50: '))
    userChoice3 = int(input('Chose a number between 1 and 50: '))


    if userChoice1 == lottoNumber1:
        lottoNumber1 = lottery(lottoNumber1,lottoNumber2,lottoNumber3)
        print('You win $1,000')
    else:
        print('You effing suck')





main()
```

I'm getting a message error saying that lottoNumber1 is reference before the assignment in the main function.  I'm not to sure what that means.  Anyone know what I could do to make this code smoother.  I want to make it so the user has to chose 3 numbers and if he gets them equal to the 3 lotto numbers he wins 10000

Thanks guys.

Comment: Check your program, in your if you compare the variable `userChoice1` to the variable `lottoNumber1`, which is not defined. Maybe you want to compare with a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `lottonumber1` before it has been defined (`lottery` hasn't been called yet when `if userChoice1 == lottonumber1:` is evaluated).

Even if you moved the call to `lottery` to before the `if` it would still fail because you're (needlessly) calling it with the parameters `lottoNumber1,lottoNumber2,lottoNumber3` which also aren't defined yet.

Also, the `for` statement is useless here (it's only executed once, and even if you iterated over an actual `range` of more than one element, it still wouldn't change anything because the same variable would be set to a random value a few times in a row).

This would work (although it's not making much sense):

```
import random

def lottery():                          # no parameters!
    lottoNumber1 = random.randint(1,50)
    print(lottoNumber1)
    lottoNumber2 = random.randint(1,50)
    print(lottoNumber2)
    lottoNumber3 = random.randint(1,50)
    print(lottoNumber3)
    return lottoNumber1,lottoNumber2,lottoNumber3

userChoice1 = int(input('Choose a number between 1 and 50: '))
userChoice2 = int(input('Choose a number between 1 and 50: '))
userChoice3 = int(input('Choose a number between 1 and 50: '))

lottoNumber1, lottoNumber2, lottoNumber3 = lottery()

if userChoice1 == lottoNumber1:
    print('You win $1,000')
else:
    print('You effing suck')
```

Perhaps it would make more sense to write a `lottery` function that returns an `n`-tuple of random values between `min_value` and `max_value`:

```
def lottery(n=3, min_value=1, max_value=50):
    return [random.randint(min_value, max_value) for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: `userChoice1 == lottoNumber1 and userChoice2 == lottoNumber2 and userChoice3 == lottoNumber3`

Comment: Thanks man, I actually got a something that I wanted now. I stopped using two functions because it made it to complicated.  Make the whole lottery game one function is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: `lottoNumber1` is not defined in function `main`.

Further, I suggest you don't repeat the same code but move it to a function. Instead of constructs like

```
userChoice1 = int(input('Chose a number between 1 and 50: '))
userChoice2 = int(input('Chose a number between 1 and 50: '))
userChoice3 = int(input('Chose a number between 1 and 50: '))
```

it would be much nicer to write

```
def inputNumber():
    return int(input('Chose a number between 1 and 50: '))

...

def main():
    ....
    userChoice1=inputNumber()
    userChoice2=inputNumber()
    userChoice3=inputNumber()
```

That way you **don't** have to **repeat yourself**, your code only contains the text once and you could add a check if the number is really between 1 and 50 at **one point** in your code.